# C++ line jumping and file reading

Tags: c++

I have a file with numbers in it. I would like to read certain lines (ones that haven't been read already but are no long easily accessible due to the way my code runs)

for example..

I have code like

```
for (c=0; c < 5;c++)
{
in >> tmp;
}
```

when implemented this reads 5 parts of the first line (lines are all the same length).

I want to be able to call this same section of code again and be able to read the second..third.ect

what do I need to do to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `in` is an input stream (`istream`), you can use its `seekg` method in order to seek back to the beginning of the file.

```
// read it the first time
for (c=0; c < 5;c++)
{
    in >> tmp;
}

in.seekg(0, in.beg); // seek to the beginning

// read it the second time
for (c=0; c < 5;c++)
{
    in >> tmp;
}
```

Check out the [documentation of the `seekg` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/).